# Setting a block OR model variable from 'update layout xml' in CMS page

Tags: layout, cms, model, xml

is  this possible?  I need to dynamically assign a variable used in a templates Model class.  This variable will be generated via a CMS page.  Below is the template and block in question.  How can I pass a dynamically assigned variable to it's model?

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" ></block>
</reference>
```

If possible i'd like to assign a variable to this via the block and pass it to the model using session variables (if I cant access this variable from the block outright).

This is the location of the block i'd like to access this variable:

```
code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php
```

Of course, I will extend this later as it is core atm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always set a variable on a block like that:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
        <action method="setMyVar">
            <value>myvalue</value>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

This will set the variable `my_var` with the value `myvalue` in the specified block. You will be able to get the value of this variable via `$this->getMyVar()`. Note that this will only work *after* the `loadLayout()` method of the respective `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` has been called.

Comment: How do I call it?  Will I be able to get this data from within the block and then pass it to the model for use?

Comment: You "call it" via layout XML as shown above. You should be able to use it in the block, at least after calling `$this->loadLayout()`.

Comment: okay, how do I manipulate this assigned variable within the block itself?  I tried to log this: Mage::log($this->getData('MyVar')); however it doesn't show anything within the log.

Comment: Via `$this->getMyVar()` or via `$this->getData('my_var')`.

Comment: Both methods aren't showing up in the log when I attempt to log them within the block.  I'm relatively sure this is the correct block i'm working within.  I updated the Q with it's location.

Comment: I'm able to retrieve this variable from the template, however, not the block.. Which is quite unfortunate as this is rendered after I need to use this variable in the model class.

Comment: @easymoden00b see my edited answer

Comment: So in other words, it's impossible to set a variable within the layout and have it be used to manipulate things within the model of this section.

Comment: If the model is used before the call of `loadLayout()`, yes.

Comment: Anything you could think of as to how I could achieve this functionality?  I'm not sure where the correct loadLayout() is located but it's probably after prepareProductCollection() in Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer.

Comment: I cannot really think of a nice and clean solution, no. You could override the specific model (not nice) or overload the specific controller.

Comment: I  just achieved the correct functionality, thanks a TON man.  I ended up just instantiating the block in the front of the CMS section and then passing the variables from the block to the model before it is called.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but came across it and noticed that the correct way to pass a variable to a method should be with an argument tag:

```
   <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <action method="setMyVar">
                <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">myvalue</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: This worked for Magento 2.3.4. Thanks.